# Fill textbox from google map after click on marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I fill my textbox of address after clicking on google maps marker

I want to use google maps in another language (persian || farsi)

Answer (score 0):

To change language to Farsi add &language=fa to the  tag as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=fa">
```

For your text book, check out this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/VmLwDw9VXHo